# How can I get ls to print output as it goes along?

Tags: ls

It seems that under most situations ls will read the whole directory before producing any output - typically because it needs to sort or columnise the output.  Normally this is fine but when reading a very large directory from a slow network server this effectively causes ls to hang.

Is there a way to get ls to print partial output as it goes along?  I've tried the following, on Mac OS X 10.6.8, but they do not appear to work:

- `ls -lf`
- `ls -1f`

Just in case what I want is not clear, the following Perl script does roughly the right thing:

```
opendir(DIR, ".") or die "can't opendir $dir: $!";
while($filename = readdir DIR) {
    print $filename, "\n";
}
closedir DIR;
```

... only I'd like to be able to use `-l`, `-lO`, and not have to write it myself!

Comment: The particular scenario in which the need for this arises is trying to ls the bands/ subdirectory of a large .sparsebundle that resides on a slow Drobo FS.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try the `find` command with the `-ls` option or even `-exec ls -lf {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the `-f` option, which prevents sorting of the output, but the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) notes that with `-l`,

> If the output is to a terminal, a total sum for all the file sizes is output on a line before the long listing.

You may be able to prevent this summation (which would require `stat`ing all the files in the directory first) by piping the output to `cat`, to prevent outputting to a terminal.

I don't know why the `-1f` form is not working for you; it seems to work fine for me on GNU ls. Another quirk of GNU ls (that may not apply to you) is that `-lf` is the same as `-f`, but `-fl` is a combination of `-f` and `-l` (long, unsorted listing). Try switching the order of some of your flags to be sure this is not a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried find?

Try

```
find . -ls
```